# I can't start the docker service with iptables error

Tags: centos, docker, iptables, nat

This is my linux version information `CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)`,
and my iptables version is `v1.4.21`

After I installed docker using the command `yum install docker`,
I am trying to start docker with the command `service docker start`, but I can't start docker.

The error message received is

```
[root@ssd-master ~]# systemctl status docker.service
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-01-30 15:20:28 KST; 7s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 54831 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 54831 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: 2015/01/30 15:20:28 docker daemon: 1.3.2 39fa2fa/1.3.2; execdriver: native; graphdriver:
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: [a20f268b] +job serveapi(fd://)
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: [a20f268b] +job init_networkdriver()
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: [info] Listening for HTTP on fd ()
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: Unable to enable network bridge NAT: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I POSTROUTING -t nat -s 172.17.42.1/16 ! -o ...o insmod?)
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: (exit status 3)
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: [a20f268b] -job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master docker[54831]: 2015/01/30 15:20:28  (exit status 3)
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jan 30 15:20:28 ssd-master systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

This is the output of `lsmod | grep -E 'iptable|nat|conntrack'`

```
nf_conntrack_ipv6      18738  4
nf_defrag_ipv6         34841  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14656  0
nf_defrag_ipv4         12758  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           12760  4
nf_conntrack          105026  4 xt_state,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
ebtable_nat            12807  0
ebtables               35009  3 ebtable_broute,ebtable_nat,ebtable_filter
iptable_mangle         12695  1
iptable_security       12705  1
iptable_raw            12678  1
iptable_filter         12810  1
ip_tables              27240  4 iptable_security,iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_raw
iptable_security,iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_raw
```

Comment: What's the output of `lsmod | grep -E 'iptable|nat'`?

Comment: @Yoel I've added the output into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# make menuconfig

--> Networking support

--> Networking options

--> Network packet filtering framework

open those NAT, NF_NAT related options

recompile, reboot the new kernel

# make all

# make modules_install

# make install

after that, # lsmod | grep nat , if those modules shows, it should work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I've recompiled kernel with 'nat' related option on because the option has been dropped in the kernel before recompiling.